Removing Root Node from a BST?
I build my tree in main with a for loop adding nodes 1-15, removing say 5 or 15 work fine, i think my problem lies in removing the root. It wont follow pre-order when I call it after removing 1, i think this has something to do with the head pointer in tree?
other functions removed my main to be able to post as well as hasLeft and hasRight.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>




struct node {

    struct node * right; 
    struct node * left;
    int val; 

};

struct binarySearchTree{
    struct node * head; 
};


struct node* treeSearch(int k, struct node * v){

    if(v->left == NULL && v->right == NULL){
        return v; 
    }

    if(k < v->val){
        return treeSearch(k, v->left);
    }else if( k > v->val){
        return treeSearch(k, v->right);
    }else{
        return v; 
    }
}

struct node * insert(int k, struct node * v){
    if(v == NULL){
        struct node * newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        if(!newnode){
            return NULL; //failed allocation
        }

        newnode->val = k;
        newnode->left = NULL;
        newnode->right = NULL; 
        return newnode;
    }

    if(k < v->val){
        v->left = insert(k, v->left); 
    }else if(k > v->val){
        v->right = insert(k, v->right);
    }
    
    return v; 

}


struct node * findMin(struct node * root){
    struct node * cur = root;
    while (cur->left != NULL){
        cur = cur->left;
    }
    return cur;
}


struct node * removeNode(int k, struct node * root){
    struct node * temp;
    if(root == NULL){
        return NULL; 
    }

    if(k < root->val){
        root->left = removeNode(k, root->left);
    }else if(k > root->val){
        root->right = removeNode(k, root->right);
    }else{
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
            free(root);
            return NULL; 
        }else if(root->left == NULL){
            temp = root->right; 
            free(root);
            return temp; 
        }else if(root->right == NULL){
            temp = root->left; 
            free(root);
            return temp; 
            
        }else{
            struct node * minNode = findMin(root->right);
            root->val = minNode->val; 
            removeNode(minNode->val, root->right);
            return root; 
        }
    }
    
}

struct binarySearchTree * createBinaryTree(){
    struct binarySearchTree * tree = malloc(sizeof(struct binarySearchTree));

    if(!tree){
        printf("failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    tree->head = NULL; 
    return tree; 
}


void inorder(struct node * v){
    if(hasLeft(v)){
        inorder(v->left);
    }
    printf("%d ", v->val);
    if(hasRight(v)){
        inorder(v->right);
    }
}


Edit the question to provide a [mre].

When it doesn't work as intended, did you run it with a debugger, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, and so finding out where the first statement is that doesn't do what you expected?

Where do you call removeNode when you say it doesn't work correctly?

in main, i call removeNode after a few insertions and checking them with inorder. When call remove(1, head) my guess is its removing the root node, but i check to see if the tree is NULL before calling inorder but it seems as the tree is there just no printing, then the program terminates.

Please provide the code you are referring to in your previous comment. Make sure it builds the tree, executes the function and reproduces the problem you ask about. Also provide the results of your debugging session inside the question.
